# AWS EFS pricing for temporary files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs, cost-management, aws-cost-explorer

I'm using AWS EFS standard storage with my lambda function to temporarily store my media files for processing. After the processing, I remove the files from the storage. I'm confused about how would I be charged for the temporary storage of these files. I can only find the cost for data retention over the period of 1 month.

Comment: You're charged per GB-Hour. Storage duration is rounded up to the hour afaik.

Comment: but the pricing calculator by AWS does not account for this. It only takes Gb stored per month. I'm confused how they calculate Gb-Hour

Comment: It's GB, not Gb. The pricing calculator is obviously not designed to support a complex case such as "I stored 20GB at 3:52am on the 17th day of the month, but deleted it at 2pm on the 19th, then I stored another 30GB on the 28th". It's designed to give you an estimate for an average workload. If you want to calculate the cost of 20GB for 1 hour then calculate it for 1 month and divide by (30x24).